# 3D NetCDF data visualization in IDV

Tags: netcdf, grids-graticules

I am using Unidata IDV (Integrated Data Viewer) to visualize geospatial data. The data is in NetCDF format and the metadata as such:

```
netcdf tn {
dimensions:
    ansi = 5 ;
    plev = 3 ;
    Lat = 160 ;
    Long = 320 ;
variables:
    char crs ;
            crs:grid_mapping_name = "latitude_longitude" ;
            crs:long_name = "CRS definition" ;
            crs:longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0. ;
            crs:semi_major_axis = 6378137. ;
            crs:inverse_flattening = 298.257223563 ;
            crs:crs_wkt = "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AXIS[\"Latitude\",NORTH],AXIS[\"Longitude\",EAST],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]" ;
    float t(ansi, plev, Lat, Long) ;
            t:valid_min = -3.402823e+38f ;
            t:valid_max = 3.402823e+38f ;
            t:grid_mapping = "crs" ;
            t:missing_value = -9.e+33f ;
            t:_FillValue = -9.e+33f ;
            t:description = "" ;
            t:institution = "DWD" ;
            t:long_name = "Temperature" ;
            t:param = "0.0.0" ;
            t:standard_name = "air_temperature" ;
            t:units = "K" ;
    double ansi(ansi) ;
    double plev(plev) ;
            plev:axis = "Z" ;
            plev:long_name = "pressure" ;
            plev:positive = "down" ;
            plev:standard_name = "air_pressure" ;
            plev:units = "Pa" ;
    double Lat(Lat) ;
            Lat:axis = "Y" ;
            Lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
            Lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
            Lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
    double Long(Long) ;
            Long:axis = "X" ;
            Long:long_name = "longitude" ;
            Long:standard_name = "longitude" ;
            Long:units = "degrees_east" ;
}
```

According to IDV, this is not a gridded data format. Is there a way to fix this so that the tool recognizes this data?

[image]